# How to add two array's of numbers together using the IAS instruction set?

Tags: arrays, architecture, von-neumann

I have to write a program using the IAS instruction set that will loop through two arrays and add each element of the one to the other and store the result in a thrid array. So for example I have to take A(1) + B(1) and store it in C(1) and then take A(2) + B(2) and store in C(2) and so on until I get to A(20) + B(20) stored in C(20). But I don't know how to create a counter controlled loop in IAS... anyways... here is what I have done.. but it doesn't work :)

```
00000001 LOAD M(A[1]) Transfer M(A[1]) to the accumulator
00000101 ADD M(B[1]) Add M(B[1]) to AC and store result in AC
00100001 STOR M(C[1]) Transfer contents of accumulator to memory location C[1]
```

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the future. There are actually numerous solutions to this question, this is the one I went with (it may need some elaboration):

```
* Initialize a variable 'count' to 999
Label: TOP
00000001    LOAD M(A[count])            Transfer M(A[count]) to the accumulator
00000101    ADD M(B[count])             Add M(B[count]) to AC and store result in AC
00100001    STOR M(C[count])            Transfer contents of accumulator to memory location C[count]
00001010    LOAD M(address of count)    Transfer the contents of M(address of count) to the AC
00000110    SUB M(the number 1)         Subtract one from AC and store in AC
00100001    STOR M(D)                   Transfer contents of AC to location M(D)
00001111    JUMP+ M(X,0:19)             If number in accumulator is non-negative take next
                                        instruction from left half of M(X)
LH: go to TOP
RH: exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
000 010F2 13006  #[LOAD M(0F2); STOR M(006,28:39)] 
001 050F1 210F2  #[ADD M(0F1); STOR M(0F2)] 
002 010F3 12006  #[LOAD M(0F3); STOR M(006,0:19)] 
003 050F1 210F3  #[ADD M(0F1); STOR M(0F3)] 
004 010F4 12007  #[LOAD M(0F4); STOR M(007,0:19)] 
005 050F1 210F4  #[ADD M(0F1); STOR M(0F4)] 
006 01002 05000  #[LOAD M(002); ADD M(000)] 
007 21004 010F0  #[STOR M(004); LOAD M(0F1)] 
008 060F1 210F0  #[SUB M(0F0); STOR M(0F0]
009 010F0 0F000  #[JUMP+ M(000,0:19)] 
0F0 00000 00005  #ITERATOR COUNTER
0F1 00000 00001  #CONSTANT 
0F2 00000 00100  #POINTER TO ARRAY A
0F3 00000 00200  #POINTER TO ARRAY B
0F4 00000 00300  #POINTER TO ARRAY C
100 00000 00001  #FIRST ELEMENT OF THE ARRAY A
200 00000 00001  #FIRST ELEMENT OF THE ARRAY B
300 00000 00000  #FIRST ELEMENT OF THE ARRAY C
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).